# PHP: Check if method is called by child or directly

Tags: php, oop, class-design

Maybe my class structure is wrong, so hopefully I can get some advice.

I have a class called 'Character'; it is an abstract class. From it extends a class called 'savageworldsCharacter'. They both contain a method called save; the 'Character' save method does general save stuff, while the 'savageworldsCharacter' save method processes data and then calls `parent::save()`.

I now have a class called 'hellfrostCharacter', which extends from 'savageworldsCharacter'. It does some stuff differently, but also has a save method, which works largely the same. The difference is that when I call save in hellfrostCharacter, I DON'T want it to process the data in `savageworldsCharacter::save`, and instead skip straight to `Character::save`.

Is there a way I can tell if a method is called from an instantiated object or from a child class? Am I building my classes wrong?

Comment: savageworldsCharacter class should be used to save all child classes of itself. Why would savageworldsCharacter be it's own character while a totally different character extends from it? My solution would be organize the characters a bit better.

Comment: I'm pretty new to class designs; I took it from a logical direction: Savage Worlds is one system that other sub systems derived from, the code between them are almost identical, with Hellfrost having some differences, and other systems also deriving from Savage Worlds, while it being its own. Not sure how to restructure this, other than just turning Hellfrost into its own class with the same code.

Comment: My personal advice would be to rearrange the characters. Parents and childs all have something in common. It seems as if hellfrostCharacter isn't very similar to savageworldsCharacter. You should therefore, like you mentioned, make hellfrostCharacter it's own Character child.

Comment: They code between them is nearly identical, with the exception of the save method and a set of methods for skills (even wherein, its only slightly different).

Comment: Remove Character save functionality from Character. Create new class CharacterSaver and pass instance of it to Character::__constructor

Answer (score 0):

Independently from whether your design is good or bad, you can achieve it by comparing `get_class()` with `get_called_class()`:

```
<?php
    class Character {
        public function save() {
            if(get_class() == get_called_class()) {
                echo "called directly";
            } else {
                echo "called from child class";
            }
        }
    }

    class savageworldsCharacter extends Character {
    }

    $character1 = new Character();
    $character2 = new savageworldsCharacter();

    $character1->save(); //outputs "called directly"
    $character2->save(); //outputs "called from child class"
?>
```

However, as said, that's merely the technical perspective. If the behavior of the method is different depending on which child class called it, then maybe it's better to also write a separate method in the child class. If you have some similarities, you may create helper methods in the parent class, which is called by both the child save() method and the parent save() method.

These are just some basic thougs. Without further context it's difficult to give more specific tips.